# How to redirect all applications traffic to proxy server using adb shell command?

Tags: android, android-networking

**Task**: To divert all android device traffic(inc. all  apps) to a proxy server.

**Method**: Used adb shell command to setup proxy: "**adb shell settings put global http_proxy proxy:port**"

**Issue**: Not  all applications data is getting transferred via proxy.

**Question**: Why i am getting the above mentioned issue and is there any other way to setup proxy so that all traffic of android device will go  via that proxy?

**Note**: Please don't give suggestions about using VPN.

Answer (score 0):

As of Android N and newer, each individual app has to opt-in to using the proxy settings.